# Why can't I paint onto my JPanel using Graphics?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I keep running into this problem when I try to paint to my extended version of a JPanel. Every time, I eventually find a way to get it to work. But I want to know exactly why it is that painting to a JPanel in this way doesn't work?

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public MyPanel(){
    init();
}

public void init(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.add(this);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyPanel();
}

}
```

When I run this code, I see the red background I would expect from setBackground(Color.RED), but I don't see the blue rectangle that I painted using the Graphics object. It doesn't show up, even if I call repaint() on the last line in init().

What is wrong with this code, so I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: Your assumptions on how to do graphics are off. Consider reading the tutorials first. I know they've helped me and can help you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I paint onto my JPanel using Graphics?

Because this is not the right way to do it. You should override the `paintComponent` method:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel(){
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.add(this);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

If you don't do so, your drawing will be visible for just one moment, and then it will disappear. This way, whenever you call the `repaint` method (or whenever the application gets repainted itself), that method will be called and your rectangle will be filled.

Comment: If you're going to show code, don't forget to call the super paintComponent method inside of the override.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ew! Wrote the code without thinking about it, it's fixed now, thanks!

Comment: Technically, Swing doesn't have "frames", it uses a passive paint algorithm, meaning that painting is done at irregular intervals, only when the paint subsystem thinks it needs to be done

Answer (score 2):

Custom painting in Swing is typically done by overriding the `paintComponent` Method of classes that extend from `JComponent`

See [Performin a Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details

Basically, the problem is, painting in Swing is destructive process. Each time a paint cycle occurs, you are expected to clean and regenerate the output.  `getGraphics` is unreliable. It can return null and anything you `paint` using it, will be over painted on the next paint cycle